# Django forms ValueError with HiddenInput widget

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a weird problem. I have my model `GameTask` with fields like:

```
activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity,
                                 verbose_name='Activity',
                                 related_name='activities',
                                 null=True,
                                 blank=True,
                                 on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
distance = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Distance [m]', default=0)
```

I want to create form for this model and display activity and distance field only in specific category(field in GameTask) like:

```
        form.fields['activity'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
        form.fields['distance'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

        if category_slug == settings.GAME_TASK_SPORT_CATEGORY_NAME:
            form.fields['activity'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                required=False,
                queryset=Activity.objects.all(),
                widget=forms.Select(
                    attrs={'placeholder': 'Aktywności', 'class': 'form-control'}
                )
            )
```

and it works. These 2 fields display only with specific category.But when I want to save form I get error: `Cannot assign "''": "GameTask.activity" must be a "Activity" instance.` In addition I have defined structure like this:

```
MODEL_PARAMS_TASK = {
    'model': GameTask,
    'fields': ['name', 'teams', 'activity', 'distance', 'description', 'button_text', 'cycle_type', 'self_confirm',
               'confirm_attachment', 'attachment_options', 'points', 'max_points', 'image', 'multi_task_image',
               'priority', 'attrs', 'private_attrs'],
    'template_name': 'master/task_form.html',
    'success_url': 'master_task_item',
}
```

I was thinking about refactoring this and create 2 forms (1 for specific category and 1 default), but maybe there is other solution to solve this problem. If something is not clear I will explain it more specific

Comment: I feel like forms.ModelChoiceField is returning nothing , try to print it and also test what format that ['activity'] accepts.

Comment: you get **activity** column value **empty string**. which is pass your form validation but on saving in table it is not allowed. If you set **activity** column value **null** then it allow to save.

Comment: the best solution I find and works is to change activity field to `NullBooleanField` in first case. This way, instead of empty string I get Null which is acceptable by model